# Why is my simple __eq__ implementation giving an AssertionError?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, operator-overloading, equality

I am trying to implement a standard equality operator in Python 3.3, following code samples from other questions. I'm getting an assertion error, but I can't figure out what's broken. What did I miss here?

```
class RollResult:
    def __init__(self, points, unscored_dice):
        self.points = points
        self.unscored_dice = unscored_dice

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self.points == other.points and self.unscored_dice == other.unscored_dice)
```

And here's the test. Many other tests are passing, so the basic setup is right. This is my first test of the class and I've never tried unit testing equality overloads before, so it may be the fault of the test as well.

```
class TestRollResultClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_rollresult_equality_overload_does_not_test_for_same_object(self):
        copy1 = RollResult(350,2)
        copy2 = RollResult(350,2)
        self.assertNotEqual(copy1,copy2)
```

Result:

```
AssertionError: <greed.RollResult object at 0x7fbc21c1b650> == <greed.RollResult object at 0x7fbc21c1b650>
```

Comment: Why are you asserting that two things constructed to be equal aren't?

Comment: Note that your method is *wrong*. The argument `other` of `__eq__` might not be a `RollResult` instance, in which case you should return `False` and not raise an `AttributeError` (people expect to be able to use `==` between *any* objects, except for really strange cases which should be well documented). I suggest you to insert the code in a `try: ... except AttributeError: return False`.

Comment: @Bakuriu Thanks for the feedback. I've seen a lot of people say it's bad to go around checking types all the time. Is this a usual exception to that standard (lack of) practice?

Comment: Yes, it is bad practice (in python) to check the types, which means using `isinstance` or doing things like `type(something) is SomeType` etc. Using Duck-typing is *encouraged*. Duck-typing means: you assume the object provide a certain *interface*, and use it. If it fails (like in this case, with an `AttributeError`) you either fail the operation (possibly raising a different exception, or sometimes letting the exception through), *or* you continue assuming a different interface. In this case the `__eq__` should first assume a "compatible interface", and otherwise fail *returning `False`*.

Comment: At least, this is what people expect from the `__eq__` method. Letting `__eq__` raise an exception breaks the [least astonishment's principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). In this case the expectation is: two objects with uncompatible interfaces should be considered unequal, not raise an exception when compared with `==` or `!=`. Note however that this isn't true for the other comparison operators, since it's fine to have unorderable instances where `<` doesn't make sense.

Comment: So in this case I'm not directly checking types, I'm just observing that if they don't have both attributes (which was why I hadn't checked types, because the attributes were the important part), it should give False, not an error. Gotcha.

Comment: @Bakuriu: Actually, if `other` isn't a `RollResult`, you should return `NotImplemented`. This is generally true even if you don't expect other objects to implement a meaningful equality comparison with `RollResult` objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `__eq__()` seems to be working correctly.  You are using `assertNotEqual()`, which will raise the AssertionError if the two arguments are equal.  You provided the same arguments to each `RollResult` object used in the assertion so they are equal, hence the failure.

It looks like you either want to be using `assertEqual()`, or change it so that `copy1` and `copy2` are constructed differently.

Comment: In short, I tested exactly the opposite of what I meant to. _headdesk_  That does clear it up.

Comment: Happens to us all from time to time :)

Comment: Often it is auto-completion's fault... (at least in my case).

Comment: Usually I'd have figured this out, but I am new at both Python and unit testing, so I thought the failure notice was a more serious error that would pop up in actual practice. Now I Know.